# SvcUtil doesn't generate .xsd files

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I want to update my WCF services, by adding a couple of new methods at the service description. I've build the new dll's with the new methods, copied them in the bin folder of the WCF website hosted on IIS of the remote server and tried to generate the new proxies with svcutil.

Svcutil however doesn't generate the .xsd files. The mex endpoint is set, httpGetEnabled is set to true. Could any change in IIS settings cause this? Because thats the only thing that might have changed since I last updated the services successfully, about a month ago.

Comment: Took me a few hours but got it. Had to set `Load User Profile` property to true on the Application Pool my WCF Service was running on.